Is my evaluation for this multiple linear regression correct?
I'm working on a multiple linear regression, following the tutorial by RegenerativeToday at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH_ezgftiy0, using the insurance dataset at https://github.com/rashida048/Datasets/blob/master/insurance.csv. I'm going a bit further than the video, though, and am applying MSE, MAE, Adjusted R2, and RMSE to my model. The issue I'm concerned about is that the numbers I'm getting seem extremely large.  For the training data:
Number of Observations in Training Data:  535
Dependend Variables:  6
R2:  0.738388485444704
Adjusted R2:  0.7354156273247574
Mean Squared Error:  40267096.874797866
Mean Absolute Error:  4539.378629153684
Root Mean Squared Error:  6345.636049664199

and for the test data:
Number of Observations in Test Data:  803
Dependend Variables:  6
R2:  0.7544700183565812
Adjusted R2:  0.7526192898517313
Mean Squared Error:  34,610,344.63969177
Mean Absolute Error:  4166.692650134549
Root Mean Squared Error:  5883.0557229803435

If I'm understanding this correctly, that means I can expect the model's predictions to deviate $34,610,344 from the true insurance charges.  Can someone let me know if this is expected for this dataset?
My code, if you need it, is here:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

insurance = pd.read_csv('insurance.csv')

insurance['sex'] = insurance['sex'].astype('category')
insurance['sex'] = insurance['sex'].cat.codes
insurance['smoker'] = insurance['smoker'].astype('category')
insurance['smoker'] = insurance['smoker'].cat.codes
insurance['region'] = insurance['region'].astype('category')
insurance['region'] = insurance['region'].cat.codes

x = insurance.drop(columns = 'charges')
y = insurance['charges']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.6, random_state=0)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_intercept = lr.intercept_
coefficient = lr.coef_

y_predict_train = lr.predict(x_train)
plt.scatter(y_train, y_predict_train)
plt.xlabel("Actual Charges")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Charges")
plt.show()

n_train = len(y_train)
print(f"Number of Observations in Training Data: ", n_train)
p = len(x.columns)
print(f"Dependend Variables: ", p)

#R2
r2 = r2_score(y_train, y_predict_train)
print(f"R2: ", r2)
#Adjusted R2: 1 - (1-R^2)*((n-1)/(n-p-1)).  In this case, n is len(y_train)=535, and p = 6
ar2 = 1 - (1-r2)*((n_train-1)/(n_train-p-1))
print(f"Adjusted R2: ", ar2)
#MSE
mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_predict_train)
print(f"Mean Squared Error: ", mse)
#MAE
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_predict_train)
print(f"Mean Absolute Error: ", mae)
#RMSE
sqmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print(f"Root Mean Squared Error: ", sqmse)

y_predict_test = lr.predict(x_test)
plt.scatter(y_test, y_predict_test)
plt.xlabel("Actual Charges")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Charges")
plt.show()

n_test = len(y_test)
print(f"Number of Observations in Test Data: ", n_test)
p = len(x.columns)
print(f"Dependend Variables: ", p)
#Show R2
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_predict_test)
print(f"R2: ", r2)
ar2 = 1 - (1-r2)*((n_test-1)/(n_test-p-1))
print(f"Adjusted R2: ", ar2)
#MSE
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict_test)
print(f"Mean Squared Error: ", mse)
#MAE
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_predict_test)
print(f"Mean Absolute Error: ", mae)
#RMSE
sqmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print(f"Root Mean Squared Error: ", sqmse)
```


"Dependend Variables:  6" Shouldn't this be "Independent Variables: 6"?

Your results would be easier to read if you rounded them up a bit. What is the point of having some 10+ decimal digits when the overall scale of the data is in the thousands or (for squares) millions AND when your sample size does not warrant estimation precision at this high level?

You should be using the root MSE, not the MSE, as a measure of expected error; that is, the error is on the order of \$6K, not $36M. (The units of MSE are the square of the units of the response variable, i.e. "dollars squared", so you can't compare MSE directly to the response variable.
Examples in R because I'm too lazy to do them in Python ...
dd <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rashida048/Datasets/refs/heads/master/insurance.csv")
m <- lm(charges ~ ., data = dd)
mean(residuals(m)^2)
## [1] 36501893
sqrt(mean(residuals(m)^2))
## [1] 6041.68

You can also compute the scaled RMSE, $\sqrt{\sum((y-\hat y)/y)^2}$, which is unitless:
sqrt(mean((residuals(m)/dd$charges)^2))
## [1] 0.631384

or the scaled mean absolute deviation:
mean((abs(residuals(m))/dd$charges))
## [1] 0.4203527

These can both be interpreted as proportions.
However, I would also say that there's a lot of structure in the data that your model hasn't handled (violations of the assumptions might not be too problematic in a purely predictive context, but do suggest that your model could be improved ...)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(m)



I do not know this particular dataset. However:
You are looking at the Mean Squared Error, which is about 34,510,000$^2. (It's a squared error, so its units are of course squared dollars.) This is an estimate (!) of the squared error you can expect.
However, we usually don't so much care about the squared prediction error for interpretation, but about the error on the original scale. For this, it makes more sense to look at the Root Mean Squared Error, which is about 6,346$. This sounds much more realistic, especially for an insurance dataset.
That said, two important points:

You are correct in looking at test errors. Errors on holdout data, or in production, will almost always be greater than in-sample residuals, as here. I personally almost never look at in-sample fit, simply because it can mislead so easily. Much better to always look at holdout data.

I personally would argue (Kolassa, 2020) that it makes no sense to look at both the MAE and the (R)MSE for the same model. The (R)MSE is minimized by the conditional mean, and that is what OLS tries to estimate. The MAE is minimized by the conditional median. (It is a special case of the pinball loss, which is used in quantile modeling.) The two quantities ("functionals") can be quite different, and in fact I would absolutely expect that for an insurance dataset, where the dependent variable is likely (a) bounded and nonnegative, and (b) heavily skewed.
Decide beforehand whether you want to model the expectation or the median (or something yet different, like a high quantile for "value at risk" modeling), and then use a loss function appropriate to that. Yes, that may mean using something different than OLS, which inherently uses the MSE. For instance, look at quantile regression.



While I agree with most of point 2, it is important to distinguish between estimation (training) loss and prediction (evaluation) loss as I explain here. So, if one wants the median, it is not necessarily optimal to use quantile regression at the median for estimation. But it can be simpler, and that is an understandable reason for preferring one estimation method to another.
